# Stripe android, how i can create 3ds payment with source card

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I want create a payments with 3ds. So i read the docs for one payment and created a code like this:

```
   // init code
      final PaymentAuthConfig.Stripe3ds2UiCustomization uiCustomization =
                    new PaymentAuthConfig.Stripe3ds2UiCustomization.Builder()
                            .setLabelCustomization(
                                    new PaymentAuthConfig.Stripe3ds2LabelCustomization.Builder()
                                            .setTextFontSize(12)
                                            .build())
                            .build();

            PaymentAuthConfig.init(new PaymentAuthConfig.Builder()
                    .set3ds2Config(new PaymentAuthConfig.Stripe3ds2Config.Builder()
                            .setTimeout(5)
                            .setUiCustomization(uiCustomization)
                            .build())
                    .build());
```

code for a payment

```
// payment method
 PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
                if (params != null) {
                    Map<String, String> extraParams = new HashMap<>();
                    extraParams.put("setup_future_usage", "off_session");

                    ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                            .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret, null, false, extraParams);

                    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    stripe = new Stripe(
                            context,
                            PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(context).getPublishableKey()
                    );
                    stripe.confirmPayment(PaymentUPD.this, confirmParams);
                }
```

code for one payment is work, and its work with 3ds. But now i want to save all cards and then choose some of card from saved list of card.

So i save a card like this:

```
        SourceParams cardSourceParams = SourceParams.createCardParams(cardToSave);
   Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    params.put("statement_descriptor", nameOfCard);
                    cardSourceParams.setExtraParams(params);

 stripe.createSource(cardSourceParams, new ApiResultCallback<Source>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull Source source) {
                Log.e("success", source.getId());
               String source_id = source.getId();
    // then i save this source to server
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Exception error) {
                Log.e("PaymentCore", error.getMessage(), error);
            }
        });
```

After my saving card, i get all list of card from server and i have something like this:

```
brand == Visa
 last 4 numbers ==   4242
 source_id == src_1GSficBnnQZzyRulVXsNTThC1
```

so now i want to pay with a saved card. So i get

```
source_id == src_1GSficBnnQZzyRulVXsNTThC1
```

and try do something like this:

```
String source = "src_1GSficBnnQZzyRulVXsNTThC1";

                SourceParams sourceParams = SourceParams.createSourceFromTokenParams(source);

                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithSourceParams(sourceParams, paymentIntentClientSecret, null);

                final Context context = getApplicationContext();
                stripe = new Stripe(
                        context,
                        PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(context).getPublishableKey()
                );
                stripe.confirmPayment(PaymentUPD.this, confirmParams);
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter returnUrl
```

what should i put to returnUrl ? I haw no any returnUrl

My second question is: How i can make a payment with 3ds with a already saved cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using "sources" for any new Card-related integrations, and should prefer to use [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) instead, just as with your one-time payment.

Stripe has a complete guide for [saving card details for later use](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#android) *without* payment. Use this if you do not intend to take payment up front. It includes a section for how to [take payment with the card later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#android-create-payment-intent-off-session).

If you do intend to take payment right away **and** save the card for later, follow the [guide for that scenario instead](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#android).

Note that in all cases if a card has been previously authenticated via 3ds, you must always be ready to handle exceptions or authentication challenges with a [recovery flow for your customer](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#android-check-status).